# Nginx try_files to PHP script in a RegEx location

Tags: nginx, nginx-location

I've got a bunch of URLs such as `https://example.com/uploads/x/y/z.pdf` that I need to route to a PHP script to perform some additional permission checks. I thought the following location block would be sufficient, but it is resulting in a 404:

```
location ~ ^/uploads/(?<upload_path>.*) {
    try_files /file-pickup.php?path=$upload_path =404;
}
```

The file `file-pickup.php` definitely exists in `root`, and if I hit that path directly, such as `https://example.com/file-pickup.php?path=x/y/z.pdf`, my PHP script is correctly invoked.

I changed `=404` to `=403` also, just to ensure that this block was picking up the directive.

The goal of this is to not have a 301/302 redirect, at least by Nginx. My script will take care of the logic and either pass through or redirect as needed.

The above directive is followed immediately by the following blocks, both of which are working correctly.

```
location / {
        try_files $uri $uri/ /index.php?$args;
}

location ~ \.php$ {
        try_files $uri =404;

        include fastcgi.conf;
        fastcgi_pass unix:/var/run/php-fpm/example.sock;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try_files don't hendles $query_string parameters

> [nginx try_files](https://nginx.org/en/docs/http/ngx_http_core_module.html#try_files) Checks the existence of files in the specified order and uses the first found file >for request processing; the processing is performed in the current context. The >path to a file is constructed from the file parameter according to the root and >alias directives. It is possible to check directory’s existence by specifying a >slash at the end of a name, e.g. “$uri/”. If none of the files were found, an >internal redirect to the uri specified in the last parameter is made.

Try this:

```
location ~ ^/uploads/(?<upload_path>.*) {
  rewrite ^ /file-pickup.php?path=$upload_path;
}
location ~ \.php$ {
....your php hendler...
}
```

**UPDATE**

this work for me

```
location ~ ^/uploads/(?<upload_path>.*) {
  try_files $uri /file-pickup.php?path=$upload_path;
}
```

without **=404**

last parametr must be either code or file

> try_files file ... uri;
> try_files file ... =code;

if you set **=404**, nginx interprets the previous options as a check for the existence of the file/dir, can't find `"/file-pickup.php?path=$upload_path"` file/dir and return 404.

Comment: Thanks @yuppi, however my understanding is that although it doesn't use the query string for _matching_, it should pass the query string along to the destination, and this is shown in their [documentation](https://www.nginx.com/resources/wiki/start/topics/tutorials/config_pitfalls/#front-controller-pattern-web-apps), however maybe they don't support the variables from the RegEx

Comment: Thanks again yuppi. One thing I didn't mention in my original post was that `/uploads/x/y/z.pdf` maps directly to a file off of root, so in `try_files $uri /file-pickup.php?path=$upload_path;` the parameter `$uri` would win I'd assume. I only put the `=404` in there because I think you need to try at least two things, if I remember correctly.

Comment: Not necessary, from docs:  `try_files file ... uri;` enough to check only `$uri`

Comment: Thanks yuppi, I will give these a test later today and report back